# How to make irregular shape clipping in OpenGL ES 1.1?

Tags: opengl-es

If I have a texture of an irregular shaped object and want to limit drawing of another texture (that is a color image of any kind) only to the shape of the object from the first texture, how can I achieve this effect in OpenGL ES 1.1 ? It's like the shape from the first texture acts like a clipping area.

I've been trying to obtain this by using a framebuffer to draw the first texture and by using opengl logical ops I tried to limit drawing only to its non-transparent pixels and after that render the next texture to the framebuffer to obtain the result. But, no success.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: Please excuse me if I wasn't clear enough. What I basically can't achieve is actually opengl masking using a framebuffer object (without using multiple texturing units or shaders).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Looking to do this right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using logic ops, you don't need to render to a texture.  Simply use stenciling - that is, draw the first shape into the stencil buffer (only), then use the stencil test to eliminate masked pixels.

(This tutorial is for desktop windows GL, but I think the stencil logic follows.)

http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=26

If you want to use texturing, I would suggest rendering the first shape into the *alpha channel* of a texture (either by OES_framebuffer or by using glCopyTexImage2D.

Then use glTexEnv with 'combine' to multiply the alpha channel of the real texture or color by the mask texture.  This will effectively "cut out" most of your pixels.  (Use depth test if you don't want masked pixels to write to the Z buffer)

There is one ugly complexity of the texture-centric approach: you need to generate texture coordinates in screen space by using the combined model view and projection matrix as a texture matrix, and then feeding the vertices into glTexCoordPointer.  This is sort of a "poor man's glTexGen" for 1.1 hardware.

Between the two approaches, I suggest stenciling if at all possible.  The availability of a stencil buffer may depend on your particular window manager though.

Answer (score 0):

Either use multitexture and modulate one texture by the other (alpha) or render one to the stencil buffer then test against it, you'd need to use alpha and then alpha test in the latter case. In either case your texture would have to have the shape as alpha output from the texture unit so the multi-texture modulate would be your fastest option I think.